# How to calculate cumulative sum using a specific column order?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataset in which I want to calculate the cumulative sum in R. Example of my data name `agfield`:

| ID | SUP | RAND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 1 |
| 2 | 5681 | 4 |
| 3 | 6514 | 3 |
| 4 | 25 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Basically, I want to calculate the cumulative sum of the SUP column in the csum column using the order of the RAND column.
Expected result:

| ID | SUP | RAND | csum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 5681 | 4 | 12720 |
| 3 | 6514 | 3 | 7039 |
| 4 | 25 | 2 | 525 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I look at several other questions/answers present on this topic here, but I can get a result that follows the order of the column RAND.
I try using  `agfield$csum<-ave(agfield$SUP, agfield$RAND, FUN=cumsum)` but it only gives me the SUP number and don’t do the cumulative sum.
I also try using group_by, but it did the same thing. Do you have any suggestion for an effective way to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you rearrange your rows it can become quite an easy problem

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,  ~SUP, ~RAND,
   1L,  500L,    1L,
   2L, 5681L,    4L,
   3L, 6514L,    3L,
   3L,   25L,    1L
  )

df_example %>% 
  arrange(RAND,ID) %>% 
  mutate(csum = cumsum(SUP))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      ID   SUP  RAND  csum
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1   500     1   500
#> 2     3    25     1   525
#> 3     3  6514     3  7039
#> 4     2  5681     4 12720
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a temporary extra column to store the initial order of the data, then calculate the cumulative sum. Then we can put it back into the initial order and remove the temporary column.

```
library(dplyr)
agfield %>%
  mutate(INITORDER = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(RAND,INITORDER) %>%
  mutate(csum = cumsum(SUP)) %>%
  arrange(INITORDER) %>%
  dplyr::select(-INITORDER)
  ID  SUP RAND  csum
1  1  500    1   500
2  2 5681    4 12720
3  3 6514    3  7039
4  3   25    1   525
```

Sample Data:

```
agfield <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), SUP = c(500L, 5681L, 6514L, 
25L), RAND = c(1L, 4L, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) order** Using the data in the Note at the end and assuming that you want to do this without changing the order of the rows, this base solution defines the permutation that would order `SUP` as `o`, applies it to `SUP`, takes the `cumsum` of that and then reverts it to the original order by applying the inverse ordering, i.e. `order(o)`.

```
o <- order(agfield$RAND)
transform(agfield, cum = cumsum(SUP[o])[order(o)])
```

giving:

```
  ID  SUP RAND  csum
1  1  500    1   500
2  2 5681    4 12720
3  3 6514    3  7039
4  3   25    1   525
```

Here is a demonstration that shows that the inverse ordering is indeed the expression shown above.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(1000)
o <- order(x)
identical(x, x[o][order(o)])
## [1] TRUE
```

If it were acceptable to sort the data frame then we could do this which is slightly shorter.

```
o <- order(agfield$RAND)
transform(agfield[o, ], cum = cumsum(SUP))
```

**2) sql**   SQL has specific features to allow taking cumulative sums in an order different than the input so with that we could do the following. Note that SQL does not guarantee an order to tables unless we ask for it explicitly so we use `order by rowid` at the end to ensure that the original order is returned -- it can be omitted if the returned order is not important.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select ID, SUP, RAND, sum(SUP) over (order by RAND, rowid) csum 
  from agfield
  order by rowid")
```

giving:

```
  ID  SUP RAND  csum
1  1  500    1   500
2  2 5681    4 12720
3  3 6514    3  7039
4  3   25    1   525
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
ID SUP RAND
1 500 1
2 5681 4
3 6514 3
3 25 1"
agfield <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this detail explanation, it really help me understand. I have apply this code for my dataset and it finally work. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
transform(
  agfield,
  csum = cumsum(SUP[RAND])[RAND]
)
```

gives

```
  ID  SUP RAND  csum
1  1  500    1   500
2  2 5681    4 12720
3  3 6514    3  7039
4  3   25    2   525
```

**Data**

```
> dput(agfield)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), SUP = c(500L, 5681L, 6514L, 
25L), RAND = c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-4L))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I think it would work, but in my complet dataset there is negative number and when I try your code I get an error message related to negatif number.

Comment: @cdes Which column has negative numbers?

Comment: the RAND column in the real dataset contain negative value